# max value in array C

Tags: c

I'm getting a compile errors, that I can't really fix. I need to create a program that initializes an in array, then write a biggest function that takes 2 parameters, an array and it's length and returns the index of the largest element in the array. I will then call this function from main. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

```
errors:part1.c: part1.c: In function 'main':
part1.c:6:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'largest'
part1.c:7:23: error: expected expression before ']' token
part1.c: In function 'largest':
part1.c:17:4: warning: statement with no effect
```

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int myArray[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
  largest(myArray,6);
  printf("%d",myArray[]);
  return 0;
} 

int largest(int array[], int length)
{
  length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
  int i = 1;
  int max = array[0];

  for(i; i<length; i++)
  {
    if(max < array[i])
    {
      max = array[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
 }
```

Comment: int myArray[num_elems];  copy/paste largest() to fall above main() so it knows about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C compiles your code in one pass. This means that everything should be defined **before** it is used. Your function `largest` is defined after its use, therefore once the compiler sees

```
largest(myArray,6);
```

it still doesn't know that `largest` exists!

The solution would be to either move the definition of `largest` above `main`, or better, **forward declare** the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int largest(int array[], int length);

int main()
{
    int myArray[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    largest(myArray,6);
    printf("%d",myArray[]);
    return 0;
} 

int largest(int array[], int length)
{
    /* implementation of largest */
}
```

---

Also, the `sizeof(array)` will not give you the number of elements in `largest` because that information is lost upon function call. You could move that expression up in the function call to compute and pass the length parameter:

```
largest(myArray,sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]));
```

---

This may also be a typo, but you probably meant to store and print the maximum value:

```
int max = largest(myArray,sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]));
printf("%d\n",max);
```

Comment: As you can guess I'm just starting with C :) Thank you Shahbaz

Comment: @KyleOrton, yes, we get a lot of people who are new to programming here. Happy to help :) Also, remember to upvote the answers that helped you and [accept the best one](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: It made sense a lot, appreciate your detailed explanation !

Comment: By `forward declare`, do you mean providing a function prototype prior to providing the function definition?

Comment: @Shahbaz Cool, thanks. Wasn't familiar with that term specifically.

Answer (score 6):

**ISSUE 1**

You use `largest()` in `main()` before you define it.  Use a prototype, or move the definition above `main()`.

**ISSUE 2**

In:

```
length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

You declare length as `int length`, but assign to it something of type `size_t`.  That caused the error `error: 'length' redeclared as different kind of symbol` in the original version of your question.

**ISSUE 3**

In

```
for(i; i<length; i++)
```

you do not assign a value to i.  Did you mean

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
```

?  Although you did previously assign a value to `i`, I believe this is causing `warning: statement with no effect` (though hard to be sure without line numbers in the provided code).

Also, arrays in C are 0-based.  You probably want to initialize `i` to 0 rather than 1.

**ISSUE 4**

In the line

```
printf("%d",myArray[]);
```

you use %d as a formatting specifier, which means that the supplied argument is expected to be an integer value.  You supply an array instead.

Comment: He has `i=1` and `max = array[0]` in the beginning of his function.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Yes, but that's what is causing `warning: statement with no effect`

Answer (score 1):

Put a declaration of `largest()` before `main()` to resolve the *implicit declaration warning*:

```
int largest(int array*, int length);

int main()
```

---

The error *error: expected expression before ']' token* is caused by:

```
printf("%d",myArray[]);
```

To print the largest value, you need to store the result of `largest()` or use it as an argument to `printf()`:

```
printf("%d", largest(myArray, 6));
```

---

This is not what you expect:

```
length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

as arrays decays to pointers when passed as arguments. It is equivalent to:

```
length = sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int);
```

Just use the `length` argument to control the iteration. Recommend make the arguments to `largest()` `const` as the function does not modify them.

---

The *warning: statement with no effect* is caused by the `i;` in the `for`:

```
for(i; i<length; i++)
```

change to:

```
for(; i<length; i++)
```

or:

```
for(i = 0; i<length; i++)
```

or if C99:

```
for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error and warnings .. the error is clearly more important.

```
  printf("%d",myArray[]);
```

the `%d` format specification implies you want to write an `int` value, this is not the case, and the likely cause of your error.

There are other warnings that deserved your attention, such as not providing a function *prototype* for your 'largest` function etc, but those are secondary to fixing the error that prevents compilation.

Of course the warnings should also be eliminated, or a conscious decision should be made to ignore them after examining them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just move the definition of largest() above the definition of main() and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Many people have pointed out many issues but surprised no one has mentioned this:

```
int largest(int array[], int length)
{
  length = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

Nope, `sizeof` does not do what you appear to think it does here.  It does not magically know the size of your allocations, only takes the size of the underlying type.  What you have done is equivalent to `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`.

You should trust the length parameter the caller gave you.  There's no way to get the actual size of the array using `sizeof`, only let the caller tell you how big it is.